# Where would you post questions about boards like BeagleBone, pcDuino

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my pcDuino, but do not know where to put it. Would it be on-topic at Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, or any other place on SE? Or, would it not have a place on the SE network? This could also apply to BeagleBone, Banana Pi, or any other board that is like the Pi, but is not made by the Raspberry Pi Foundation.

Comment: We should add the Nextthing CHIP device.  Perhaps the RaspberryPi site should morph into an embedded device site, thoughts?

Comment: I think RPi SE has already considered this. http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/567/what-would-you-think-about-broadening-the-topic-to-include-arduino-robotics-and?rq=1

Comment: Yes, and I see that there was an embedded beta site that didn't get enough traction and was closed.  My motivation is that I'm starting to work with the Nextthing CHIP device and it's so close to the raspberry pi zero that users of the CHIP would benefit from the experience of the Raspberry Pi users.

Comment: I have never played with CHIP. You could try to start a CHIP SE on Area 51.

Comment: While users of the CHIP might benefit from the experience of the Raspberry Pi users, would Raspberry Pi users benefit from the experience of having lots of CHIP newbies asking unrelated questions? Unless/until the benefit is mutual, Area 51 is your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been discussed here on Meta a few times before. Current consensus is that non-Pi boards are off-topic here.

That leaves you (unfortunately) with multiple options on the network depending on the nature of the question. There is no one-page-fits-all here...

- General programming questions: https://stackoverflow.com/
- Hardware/software and networking issues (unless it's programming or electronics): https://superuser.com/
- Linux/Unix questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- Electronics and low-level hardware: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

... but checking the sites' rules about what's on- or off-topic there is of course highly recommended.